# Convertir HiddenField Value a Datetime en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Saludos,

Tengo el siguiente HiddenField

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfFecha" runat="server" />
```

y en el code behing tengo, para convertirlo en formato "dd-MM-yyyy".

```
FormAGPost.Fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(hdfFecha.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Pero me da error al momento de convertirlo. Este es el error que me da:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CentroEntrevista.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

el valor obtenido en la variable es:  "21-01-2017T00:00:00+00:00"

Comment: ¿Cual es el error? ¿Cual es el tipo y el valor de `hdfFecha`? Por favor, toma en cuenta la información en cuanto a como crear un [mcve].

Comment: Según el error que agregastes, suena a que la variable `hdfFecha` está a null. ¿Verificastes el contenido de `hdfFecha`?

Comment: hdfFecha es Var y el error qe produce es An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CentroEntrevista.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @sstan hdfFecha se esta llenando, el error propio es cuando esta haciendo la conversión.

Comment: ok, pero por favor, especifica cual es el valor contenido en la variable `hdfFecha`. Y `var` no es el tipo. Mueve el ratón encima del `var` para que te diga cual es el tipo en realidad.

Comment: Hay algo que no cuadra en la pregunta. Si de verdad el problema está en esa sentencia con ese error, solo puede ocurrir si `FormAGPost` o `hdfFecha` están a null. Pero tu dices que la variable `hdfFecha` tiene el valor `21-01-2017T00:00:00+00:00`, lo que te hubiera generado mas bien el error *System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*. Hay algo que no está correcto en la pregunta. Nuevamente, la clave está en que armes un [mcve].

Comment: Hola. Estoy de acuerdo con @sstan. Pon un punto de ruptura en esa linea y verifica que o bien `FormAGPost` es nulo o `hdfFecha` también lo es.

Answer (score 0):

Conviertelo primero a DateTime.

```
FormAGPost.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(hdfFecha.Value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score -1):

El método `DateTime.Parse` sirve para convertir un formato de texto a formato de fecha.

FormAGPost.Fecha = DateTime.Parse(hdfFecha.Value.ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Publica el error que da para que la respuesta sea más precisa.

Comment: Este es el error que me da An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CentroEntrevista.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Ya intentaste depurar? estás seguro que el error te lo da al intentar convertir la fecha? El NullReferenceException ocurre cuando no has instanciado...